# Step by Step guide on how to setup CruiseControl.Net + Subversion

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

I'm looking for a step by step guide (like for dummies guide), to setup CC.NET + Subversion. And I'm wondering if a really need to do Unit testing to use CC.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google can really be your friend in this case. This was the first result for "Subversion CruiseControl.NET" and things look pretty thorough:

[Continuous Integrion + CruiseControl.NET + SubVersion + MSBuild + .NET 2.0](http://justinram.wordpress.com/2006/07/20/continuous-integration-cruisecontrolnet-subversion-msbuild-net-20/)